# Сложное предложение с союзной и бесоюзной связью

Tags: синтаксис

В предложении "Переплелись их ветки между собой как змеи, **протянулись всюду корни, и каждый шаг много стоил пота и крови тем людям"**, какие отношения между частями сложного предложения - **последовательности?** Сомневаюсь между последними двумя предложениями (выделены жирным).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Переплелись их ветки между собой как змеи, (2) протянулись всюду корни, (3) и каждый шаг много стоил пота и крови тем людям".

Сложное предложение с бессоюзой и союзной сочинительной связью.

Отношения между предложениями 1 и 2 однородные перечислительные, перечисляемые события являются **одновременными.**

Предложение 3 связано с 1 и 2 неоднородной союзной сочинительной связью и имеет с**оединительно-следственное значение** (значение: **и поэтому**).